# What was the Apollo service module propellant used for on the LEO missions?

Tags: propulsion, apollo-program, low-earth-orbit, mission-design

The [Apollo service module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module) carried a lot of propellant for performing the following tasks on a Moon mission:

- Mid-course correction manoeuvres to and from the Moon.
- Braking the entire CSM/LM stack into orbit around the Moon.
- Escaping low Moon orbit to transfer the crew back to Earth.

Especially the two later are relatively expensive manoeuvres, and the same propellant in a CSM configuration without the LM sums up to multiple $km/s$ of $\Delta v$.

What was all that propellant used for when the Apollo spacecraft did ***not*** travel to the Moon? Examples are the early hardware tests in LEO before the Moon missions, the three missions to [Skylab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab) and finally the [Apollo-Soyuz test project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz_Test_Project).

Was the SM close to empty? Was it used as a last stage to reach orbit? Did the Apollo spacecraft perform some expensive plane change manoeuvre? Was a lot of fuel launched just to be ditched at re-entry?

None of those possibilities makes very much sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Apollo By The Numbers](http://georgetyson.com/files/apollostatistics.pdf), the loaded weight of the CSM was substantially lower for the LEO Apollo 7 and Apollo 9 missions.

Apollo 7 (SM loaded: 19,730 lbs / 8950kg) was a no-LM mission launched on a Saturn 1B; Apollo 9 (SM loaded: 36,159 lbs / 16400kg) was CSM+LM launched on a Saturn V.

The translunar missions by comparison had loaded SM weighing upwards of 51,000 lbs / 23000kg. The full SPS propellant load is 40,590 lb / 18,410 kg.

Both 7 and 9 were 10-day missions, so would have had a full load of consumables other than fuel; the mass difference must be almost all SPS propellant.

Apollo 9 did [7 test burns of the SPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_9#Summary_of_maneuvers), some quite lengthy, in addition to the deorbit burn, so that accounts for a great deal of fuel usage.

Likewise Apollo 7 did [several SPS burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_7#On-orbit_operations).

So in each case they loaded a reasonable amount of fuel for the mission they intended to fly.

The Saturn 1B didn't have the capability to lift a fully loaded SM, so the [Skylab and ASTP missions actually removed some tankage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module#Modifications_for_Saturn_IB_missions) and other unneeded components to save weight.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the SM load for Apollo 8 (translunar, Saturn V, but no LM)?

Comment: SM loaded weight for A8 was 51,258 lbs -- 15 pounds more than A11, and very close to all of the A10-A14 loads, despite the fact that they didn't need to brake an LM into lunar orbit.